# Plotting a global variable tick by tick

Tags: netlogo

I am very new to netlogo and i am trying to plot stock prices from a csv file. The csv file is just one column of 200 rows or so and i am reading the file in tick by tick. The issue i am having is that the plot is expecting a number but is getting a list value. Can someone help me fix this issue as i have no idea how to deal with it after googling it for an hour. This is my code below. Thank you.

```
extensions [csv]
globals [stock]

to setup
  clear-all
  file-close-all 
  file-open "stock.csv"
  reset-ticks
end


to go
    if file-at-end? [ stop ]
  set stock csv:from-row file-read-line
  tick
end
```

The plot code is simply "plot stock"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`csv:from-row` takes the string reported by `file-read-line` and parses it into a list.  In this case, if it encounters a string with a single value, say "100" it will put it in a list with a single element, `[100]`.  As the error suggests, `plot` wants the value itself, so the plot command should be

```
plot item 0 stock
```

That will extract the value from the list.

A suggestion for the future: If you get an error like this, putting  `show` commands in the appropriate places will often show you that what you expect is not what you are getting.  E.g.,

```
to go
  if file-at-end? [ stop ]
  set stock csv:from-row file-read-line
  show stock   
  tick 
end
```

would show you that stock is a list rather than a simple value.  I can't tell you how many times I've been saved by `show` in debugging a model.